# Find a basis of the vector spaces in Problem 1 and evaluate their dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of the vector spaces below and evaluate their dimension.

1. $\{(x,y,z) \in \textbf{R}^3:x+y+z=0\}$
2. $\{(x,y,z) \in \textbf{R}^3:x+y=0$ and $x+z=0\}$
3. The space of polynomials $p(x)$ of degree m with real coefficients such that $p(0)=0$.
4. The spaces of polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $\leq m$ with **complex** coefficients such that $p(0)=0$.

**Part 1:** $(x,y,-x-y)=x(1,0,-1)+y(0,1,-1)$, and this shows that the set is spanned by two linearly independent vectors (1,0,-1) and (0,1,-1).

**Part 2:** $(x,y,z)=(x,-x,-x) =x(1,-1,-1)$, and this shows that the set is spanned by one linearly independent vector (1,-1,-1).

I have no idea how to have basis for polynomials.

Comment: Something like $x,x^2,....$

Comment: The standard basis for the space of $m$-degree polynomials is $\{1,x,\dots,x^m\}$.

Comment: So for both 3 and 4 the basis is $\{x,x^2,\ldots,x^m\}$?

Comment: 4) That depends on the field you are working on. If you are considering a vector space over $\mathbb R$ then you need also something like $ix,ix^2,....$

Comment: Do we have to account for the constant as well?

Comment: @unknown p(0)=0.

Comment: Oh ok. That helps ALOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomials are defined by the sequence $a_n$ of their coefficients such that you can write $P(X)=\sum_n a_n X^n$, so a basis is simple $\{1,X,...X^n\}$ of dimension $n+1$.

As noted in the comment, $p(0)=0$ implies that $a_0=0$ and you simply remove $1$ from the basis. Technically, if the polynomial has to be of degree exactly $n$, it's not a vector space any longer as it doesn't contain 0.

For the last question, you need to precise the field you're talking about. The space described is a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space but a $2n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ vector space.